# How to run prerendered folder on Heroku with Angular

Tags: angular, heroku

I can't seem to run my Angular app on Heroku. Here is my script section in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node dist/heroku-universal-tpl/browser/index.html",
  "heroku-postbuild": "ng run heroku-universal-tpl:prerender",
  "ng": "ng",
  "start:local": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e",
  "dev:ssr": "ng run heroku-universal-tpl:serve-ssr",
  "serve:ssr": "node dist/heroku-universal-tpl/server/main.js",
  "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run heroku-universal-tpl:server:production",
  "prerender": "ng run heroku-universal-tpl:prerender"
}
```

When I check this file (dist/heroku-universal-tpl/browser/index.html) locally my app runs. Here is my log:

[image]

Comment: I was able to get it to run with: "start": "node dist/heroku-universal-tpl/server/main.js" But isn't that serving it via ssr and not using prerendering? Sorry I'm just starting to learn this stuff.